# iOS Safari Z-index not working

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a dropdown menu in HTML but it's **hidden** by some other page content on iOS. The dropdown appears perfectly on Android and PC but refuses to appear on iOS Safari browser (Tested on iOS 9 and 10).

I have specified a higher z-index  for the dropdown and a lower one for the page content. I have also tried:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
```

with no luck.

Here is my CSS:

**Dropdown**

```
.dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;        
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);  
}
```

**Page Content**

```
.newmain{
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 90;
}
```

Comment: You should include the version of the browser with questions like this. It could be that one of the other used css-properties isn't supported. On https://caniuse.com you can check which features are supported by which browser. Try narrowing it down by removing some css temporarily until you are sure that the problem is indeed *z-index*.

Comment: Sorry, its iOS 9 and 10

Comment: Try narrowing it down then. I doubt this is a *z-index* problem. What about the desktop version of Safari?

Comment: The desktop version also doesn't work. I tried removing `overflow-y` altogether but still no luck.

Answer (score 16):

It was not a Z-index issue. Turns out the parent element of the dropdown was set to `overflow: hidden`. Setting it to `Overflow: visible` solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I found the container of the element should be on the top.

I saw this: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Then I replace it by `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;`

That solved my bug.

I hope this help you!

Comment: May universe bless you my friend.

Answer (score 8):

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
```

work for me.

Answer (score 2):

that's weird, safari is okay with `z-index`.

You're not using `position: relative` or whatever position in `.newmain`,
z-index is not gonna work without position.

Try to add position into `.newmain`

Comment: I've tried Relative, Fixed and Absolute positioning but still doesn't work.

Comment: try to add `top: {any}px` into your .dropdown-content2, maybe it's appearing somewhere above, cause fixed position is weird and not relate with parent elements' position